# How to overwrite destination folder of dotnet publish

Tags: .net, directory, publish, overwrite

I am trying to run a `dotnet publish -c Release -o [destination-folder-name]` and if the destination folder exists overwrite it.
Is that possible , is it built in the `dotnet` command flags?

Comment: Could you clarify what goes wrong when you try that at the moment?

Comment: It says i can not create directory because a directory with the given name already exists ; this is why i was asking on how to overwrite.

Comment: That's odd - I just tried it and it worked without any problems at all. It would be worth including that in the question - along with the version of the .NET SDK you're using, and potentially a sample (minimal) project file. If we can reproduce the problem, we're more likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perform an IISreset before executing the command will solve your challenge.